# Parsley.js pattern for last name

Tags: java, regex, parsley.js

I would like to know how to create a parsley.js pattern for last name that accepts a string with empty spaces since some people can have few last names.

At the moment I'm using the next pattern but it doesn't work the way I need it.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

I would like to match the following:

```
smith
smith smith
smith smith smith ...etc
```

Only a-z A-z with possible "-" , but without numbers and foreign letters.

Comment: Show us samples of what you want to match and what you *don't* want to match.

Comment: What about hyphens ("-") or apostrophes ("'")?

Comment: Wht about letters from a "foreign" alphabet?

Comment: Do you want to match any other names than `smith`?

Comment: @Tichodroma yes, smith is just an example

Comment: In what way is this question related to Java? Also, if you are matching `A-Z` and explicitly forbid "foreign" letters (foreign to *what*, by the way?), then you are definitely not matching last names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this,

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]+[ -])*[A-Za-z]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jI6gE8/1)

It allows names which has first and last-name. First name and lastname would be separated by spaces or hypens.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s*|$))\1*
```

Try this

Comment: I think the `smith smith smith` in the question was only an example. Your pattern will only match repeating names. Furthermore, you're not allowing for the hyphens OP requested.